# To make the custom trackbar smaller by changing more than 1 value in one scroll move

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I have created a custom trackbar that gives values between 100-1600. The problem is that i havent been able to reduce the size of the trackbar. The trackbar has to have the width as 1600 for a user to be able to access all the values and keep the thumb in the trackbar at the same time. Here is my code :

```
Public Class myTrackBar
    Inherits Control
    'Public Value As Integer
    Private Pointer As New Bitmap(25, 30)
    Private Rect As New Rectangle(100, 0, 20, 30)
    Public Event Scroll(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As ValueChangedEventArgs)
    Private Moving As Boolean
    Private Offset As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        'Size = New Size(210, 50)
        DoubleBuffered = True
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Pointer)
            g.Clear(Color.White)
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkBlue, New Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50))
            'g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Blue, New Point() {New Point(0, 15), New Point(5, 20), New Point(10, 15)})
            'g.FillEllipse(Brushes.DarkBlue, 0, 0, 19, 19)

        End Using
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, New Rectangle(0, 0, Width - 100, Height))
        Dim X As Integer = 15
        ' For count As Integer = 1 To 10
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Brushes.Green, 16), New Point(0, 15), New Point(Width - 100, 15))
        ' X += 20
        'Next
        ' Using P As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1)
        'P.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot
        'e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(P, New Rectangle(100, 1, Width - 5, Height - 5))
        'End Using
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(Pointer, Rect)
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If Rect.Contains(e.Location) Then
            Moving = True
            Offset = (e.Location.X - Rect.X)
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseup(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        Moving = False
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        If Moving Then
            Rect.X = Math.Min(Math.Max(e.Location.X - Offset, 0), 1500)
            Invalidate()
            RaiseEvent Scroll(Me, New ValueChangedEventArgs(Rect.X))
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Property Value As Integer
        Get
            Return CInt((Rect.X + 100))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Rect.X = CInt(value)
        End Set
    End Property
    End Class
```

Comment: I wrote a 'high preceision' TrackerBar a few years ago, and rather than a bmp, the thumb was drawn using GraphicsPath.  I think I had a whole internal class for it since the style/shape was a property.  I am not sure how I woiuld go about it with a bmp. I dont understand the actual question - changing the thumb position/value changes the size of the trackbar?

Comment: You probably want to make some of those hardcoded things into Properties - Green for the trackline (?) for instance so that the control can be used for more than just the immediate need and can more easily be extended

Comment: @Plutonix I want the size of the trackbar to be smaller than 1600. If i want a trackbar to show values in the range of 0-2000, the width will have to be 2000 (I want it to be much smaller than 2000 and still show the values in that range).

Comment: Thats just arithmetic to scale a click location into the range (0-2000 being another of those Property based values).  In my experience you need several internal rectangles: The trackline rect, the "hot" rect where clicks register, a thumb rect and maybe a border rect if you want the ability to do borders

Comment: @plutonix I am using various rectangles for all the things that you mentioned. The arithmetic is what i am not able to understand (where do i apply it and how)

Comment: There is only one rect there (cleverly named Rect) which is why I mentioned it. I used the LineRect - get the click location inside that; if it is 41.5% from the left, then the new value is 41.5% of whatever the max is. If you have a provision to set the value in code, do the opposite.  Note that there are several OK already done TrackBars (and numerous bad ones)  on CodeProject

Comment: @Plutonix Have used New Rectangle inside a lot of the graphics. I will have a look. 
Thanks!

Comment: [Example TrackerBar](https://i.imgur.com/WxhMTYK.jpg)  The "hot" rect is a few px taller than the Thumb and as long as the trackline; clicks outside that dont register so the user doesnt have to precisely click the tiny line rect.  Another Rect you may want is one for displaying Interval Ticks. Yet another could be a HoverRect - a larger thumb rect that when the mouse hovers inside it you display the current value.  Most of the Rects are static so no need to recalc them unless and until the control size changes

Comment: I wrote that a long time ago, I think the hot rect may be 2ce as tall as the LineRect and not as tall as the Thumb because some of the thumb styles supported were much taller than others.  I didnt want the hot zone to vary that much

Comment: @Plutonix Do you mind sharing that code with me?

Comment: Its way too large to post here.  There is an abstract base class, a class for a Horiz version, Vert version and specialty one for **[volume type control](https://i.imgur.com/QwzjqFY.jpg)**. There is also some after thought functionality that may or may not be implemented correctly, some isnt even Slider/Tracker related.  Tip: in all cases whatsoever make sure the thumb width is an odd number so you can position the thumb tip exactly where the calcs say the current value is

Comment: @plutonix thank you

Comment: Part of the cool-but-not-really-tracker related functionality is to [display the previous sampling points as IntervalTicks](https://i.imgur.com/BgZrAZK.jpg). The hashes show exactly above the thumb tip but if the thumb width is not odd it becomes very difficult for the thumb tip to line up with a hash mark including the one the user may have just added "at this exact point". Without them it is not as obvious but rounding errors creep in between the actual value and thumb location and where the user clicks.

Comment: @Plutonix I am not letting the user resize the trackbar or allowing him to click at random points on the trackbar. The only thing the user can do is drag the thumb.

Comment: Dragging is actually more difficult.  You  have to cancel the drag when the mouse leaves the control or perhaps the HotRect.  Using a dragging var like that can mean the mouse reenters at a different location and the dragging continues from there.

Comment: @Plutonix That is true if the user clicks on it, keeps it the mouse clicked and leaves the trackbar then the dragging will continue. Are you suggesting creating rect too see if the mouses focus is over the cursor?

Comment: @plutonix why cant they add a property to the vb trackbar to atleast increase the thumb size ugh

Comment: Not just suggesting, but explicitly noted it several hours ago: the Hot Rect is the area where user actions actually register - mine starts 50% above the LineRect and extends 50% below.  Actions (clicks, drags etc) dont register outside it.  It allows the control to be sized to fit an area and leave the interactive zone the same size somewhere near the LineRect and prevents incidental clicks from triggering stuff.

Comment: @Plutonix Yes Sir!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various dlls available online for trackbars. If you want to simply use it in a project you can simply import the dll files into the project and use them like any other element.